# How to tell Application's AndroidManifest.xml take @string from a specific package

Tags: android, android-manifest

In my application's `AndroidManifest.xml` I am trying to tell it to use a string from a  `/res/values` in a particular package instead of the first one one found in one of the  libraries (the string `my_label` could be defined in more than one libraries) :

```
   <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
                android:label="com.example.projname.appmodule:@string/my_label">
```

The above notation/syntax doesn't work, however. It only accepts the following form which doesn't allow pin-pointing a specific resource file:

```
   <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
                android:label="@string/my_label">
```

Is it possible at all to tell Application's AndroidManifest.xml take a @string value from a specific `/res/values`?

**EDIT:** The interesting thing is, the build environment doesn't complain at all about the `"com.example.projname.appmodule:@string/my_label"` syntax. But when the application runs, it displays `com.example.projname.appmodule:@string/my_label` instead of the string value.

As @Nikola Despotoski suggested below, a workaround could be setting this programmatically in the application, but since the build environment doesn't complain about this syntax, I am still wondering whether this a bug in the build env or something that I have been missing.

My workaround, for now, is to make sure that `my_label` is unique, e.g. my_3F2504E0-4F89-11D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301_label so it can't appear in any other package.

Comment: If get your question correctly you need to concatenate the "com.example.projname.appmodule:" with value "@string/my_label"

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v6rxmx/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wbit.help.sib.mediation.ui.doc/topics/tconcatxml.html

Comment: @Nikola Despotoski Thanks but I am not using WebSphere. These are plain Android XML files. I am not even sure that what I am looking for is possible. But perhaps I am missing something in the syntax (which works fine in .java files). Any ideas?

Comment: Does it matters to you if you set the label of your application in your java code?

Comment: @Nikola Despotoski I can of course do that programmatically, but the build environment doesn't complain about this syntax and I was wondering whether this is a bug in the build environment or something that *I* am missing.